# How to connect with a Qualcomm/Huawei 3g modem

Tags: networking, usb-modem, 3g

I have a 3g modem which `lsusb` reports as a `Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800` modem. However Windows' Network Connections panel shows it as a `Qualcomm USB Modem 6000.` So when I try to connect to the internet on Ubuntu 14.04, using sakis3g as compiled from here: https://github.com/trixarian/sakis3g-source, by launching sakis3g with `sudo sakis3g` and choosing the Connect with 3G option, an error box shows with the following error message, `Modem responded "ERROR" while checking for PIN`. Additionally, when I try to connect with Network Manager, I am told that "I am now registered on the ..", however when I click on the wifi symbol, and click on "not enabled", I see the following error message:

> Connection activation failed
>
> (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/13' failed in libnm-glib

So how can I get my 3G USB Modem working with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Network Manager and Sakis3G don't really work well together. Sometimes you need to run Sakis3g twice or remove and plug the device back in to get it to work. This is because ModemManager can be quite forceful by locking device ports. Alternatively, you can switch the device using Sakis3G (at which point Network Manager should pick it up) and then connecting using Network Manager.

As for the pin - either remove the required pin from the sim card by putting it in a normal mobile phone or provide your pin for switching in /etc/sakis3g.conf using the SIM_PIN="" variable.

Reference: http://web.archive.org/web/20120908202215/http://wiki.sakis3g.org/wiki/index.php?title=Sakis3G_configuration#SIM_PIN